# unsigned char pointer in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, unsigned-char

In the middle of translating some code from C++ to C#, I found this,

```
unsigned char *p = m_pRecvBuffer + 5;
unsigned int noncelen1 = *p * 256 + p[1];
```

How do I translate this into C#? `m_pRecvBuffer` is a char-array, however I store it as a byte-array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something akin to

```
byte[] p = new byte[m_pRecvBuffer.Length - 5];
Array.Copy(m_precvBuffer, p, m_pRecvBuffer.Length - 5);
uint noncelen1 = p[0] * 256 + p[1];
```

But in that case I don't think you actually need to use an array copy. Just using

```
uint noncelen1 = p[5] * 256 + p[6];
```

should be enough, I guess.

Comment: I went this route since it resembled code I had already written.

Comment: @hokkaido: If you are declaring a new byte array like this and then copying data, this is far less efficient than the answer I posted. There is no reason to be allocating memory or copying arrays.

Comment: @Jonathan, note that I say the same. But you don't know how the rest of the code looks. Might be that there's something that only gets a pointer and starts reading from there and maybe refactoring that into array + offset isn't feasible. From the OP's tiny code snippet it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm I wonder if some refactoring would be in order for this piece of code. Yes you can use [pointers in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pcurnow/usingpointers10022007082330AM/usingpointers.aspx). However, based on that snippet there may be better options. It looks like you're trying to read parts of an incoming stream. Maybe C#'s [stream library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) would work better for this piece of your code?

Answer (score 2):

You analyse what the code actually does and translate behaviour, not code. While you could use `unsafe` methods and pointer arithmetic in c#, this will probably create more problems than it will solve.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. However, since I know more C# than C++ and cannot debug the code given, the first step for me to wrap my head around this is to get it working in C#, then refactor it into something nice.

Comment: ah okay. Same problem for me, I had the idea it was array indexing, but I couldn't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming RecvBuffer is declared as byte[], you would do something like this:

```
int noncelen1 = RecvBuffer[5] * 256 + RecvBuffer[6];
```